# External ADC with SPI NUCLEO-H743ZI2

Tags: stm32, spi, gpio, cdc

I have an external ADC with a serial interface that has one data_out pin and CLK pin (16 MHz)
the data_out pin transmit 16 bits of valid data then. An all-zero pattern follows the data after all valid ADC data are streamed to the output. All I am trying to do is to  read the valid data from the ADC using SPI by setting it to receive-only master mode then save to my PC preferably using (CDC USB virtual com). The data is stable in falling edge.

```
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define Buffsize 1000
#define tx 50

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */
/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi1_rx;


UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart3_tx;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t transferComplete = 0;
uint16_t Buffer[Buffsize];
volatile uint16_t count=0;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
            /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
                 HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1,Buffer,Buffsize);
             /* Infinite loop */
             /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
             /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
            while (1) {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
if (transferComplete) {
            transferComplete=0;
            CDC_Transmit_FS(Buffer,Buffsize);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

The data is callback fucntions:

```
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback (SPI_HandleTypeDef * hspi1){
     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_0);
     transferComplete = 1 ;
}
void HAL_SPI_RxHalfCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi1){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_1);

}
void HAL_SPI_ErrorCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi1){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_14);}
```

I can not make sure if the data I am receiving is correct. Can you help me out?
And I was not able to transmit the data at all. I was hoping that I could transmit it continuously to my PC so I can process it in Matlab.
.ioc file

```
    #MicroXplorer Configuration settings - do not modify
Dma.Request0=USART3_TX
Dma.Request1=SPI1_RX
Dma.RequestsNb=2
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.Direction=DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.EventEnable=DISABLE
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.FIFOMode=DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.Instance=DMA1_Stream0
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.MemDataAlignment=DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.MemInc=DMA_MINC_ENABLE
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.Mode=DMA_CIRCULAR
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.PeriphDataAlignment=DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.PeriphInc=DMA_PINC_DISABLE
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.Polarity=HAL_DMAMUX_REQ_GEN_RISING
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.Priority=DMA_PRIORITY_LOW
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.RequestNumber=1
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.RequestParameters=Instance,Direction,PeriphInc,MemInc,PeriphDataAlignment,MemDataAlignment,Mode,Priority,FIFOMode,SignalID,Polarity,RequestNumber,SyncSignalID,SyncPolarity,SyncEnable,EventEnable,SyncRequestNumber
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.SignalID=NONE
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.SyncEnable=DISABLE
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.SyncPolarity=HAL_DMAMUX_SYNC_NO_EVENT
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.SyncRequestNumber=1
Dma.SPI1_RX.1.SyncSignalID=NONE
Dma.USART3_TX.0.Direction=DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH
Dma.USART3_TX.0.EventEnable=DISABLE
Dma.USART3_TX.0.FIFOMode=DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE
Dma.USART3_TX.0.Instance=DMA1_Stream2
Dma.USART3_TX.0.MemDataAlignment=DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD
Dma.USART3_TX.0.MemInc=DMA_MINC_ENABLE
Dma.USART3_TX.0.Mode=DMA_CIRCULAR
Dma.USART3_TX.0.PeriphDataAlignment=DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD
Dma.USART3_TX.0.PeriphInc=DMA_PINC_DISABLE
Dma.USART3_TX.0.Polarity=HAL_DMAMUX_REQ_GEN_RISING
Dma.USART3_TX.0.Priority=DMA_PRIORITY_LOW
Dma.USART3_TX.0.RequestNumber=1
Dma.USART3_TX.0.RequestParameters=Instance,Direction,PeriphInc,MemInc,PeriphDataAlignment,MemDataAlignment,Mode,Priority,FIFOMode,SignalID,Polarity,RequestNumber,SyncSignalID,SyncPolarity,SyncEnable,EventEnable,SyncRequestNumber
Dma.USART3_TX.0.SignalID=NONE
Dma.USART3_TX.0.SyncEnable=DISABLE
Dma.USART3_TX.0.SyncPolarity=HAL_DMAMUX_SYNC_NO_EVENT
Dma.USART3_TX.0.SyncRequestNumber=1
Dma.USART3_TX.0.SyncSignalID=NONE
File.Version=6
GPIO.groupedBy=Group By Peripherals
KeepUserPlacement=false
Mcu.CPN=STM32H743ZIT6
Mcu.Family=STM32H7
Mcu.IP0=CORTEX_M7
Mcu.IP1=DMA
Mcu.IP2=NVIC
Mcu.IP3=RCC
Mcu.IP4=SPI1
Mcu.IP5=SYS
Mcu.IP6=USART3
Mcu.IP7=USB_DEVICE
Mcu.IP8=USB_OTG_FS
Mcu.IPNb=9
Mcu.Name=STM32H743ZITx
Mcu.Package=LQFP144
Mcu.Pin0=PC13
Mcu.Pin1=PC14-OSC32_IN (OSC32_IN)
Mcu.Pin10=PB0
Mcu.Pin11=PB14
Mcu.Pin12=PD8
Mcu.Pin13=PD9
Mcu.Pin14=PD10
Mcu.Pin15=PG7
Mcu.Pin16=PA8
Mcu.Pin17=PA9
Mcu.Pin18=PA11
Mcu.Pin19=PA12
Mcu.Pin2=PC15-OSC32_OUT (OSC32_OUT)
Mcu.Pin20=PD7
Mcu.Pin21=PE1
Mcu.Pin22=VP_SYS_VS_Systick
Mcu.Pin23=VP_USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS
Mcu.Pin3=PH0-OSC_IN (PH0)
Mcu.Pin4=PH1-OSC_OUT (PH1)
Mcu.Pin5=PC0
Mcu.Pin6=PC3_C
Mcu.Pin7=PA0
Mcu.Pin8=PA5
Mcu.Pin9=PA6
Mcu.PinsNb=24
Mcu.ThirdPartyNb=0
Mcu.UserConstants=
Mcu.UserName=STM32H743ZITx
MxCube.Version=6.6.1
MxDb.Version=DB.6.0.60
NVIC.BusFault_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
NVIC.DMA1_Stream0_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:true\:true
NVIC.DMA1_Stream2_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:true\:true
NVIC.DebugMonitor_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
NVIC.EXTI0_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:true\:true\:true
NVIC.ForceEnableDMAVector=true
NVIC.HardFault_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
NVIC.MemoryManagement_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
NVIC.NonMaskableInt_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
NVIC.OTG_FS_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:true\:true
NVIC.PendSV_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
NVIC.PriorityGroup=NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4
NVIC.SPI1_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:true\:true\:true
NVIC.SVCall_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
NVIC.SysTick_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:true\:false
NVIC.UsageFault_IRQn=true\:0\:0\:false\:false\:true\:false\:false\:false
PA0.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label,GPIO_ModeDefaultEXTI
PA0.GPIO_Label=exti0
PA0.GPIO_ModeDefaultEXTI=GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING
PA0.Locked=true
PA0.Signal=GPXTI0
PA11.Locked=true
PA11.Mode=Device_Only
PA11.Signal=USB_OTG_FS_DM
PA12.Locked=true
PA12.Mode=Device_Only
PA12.Signal=USB_OTG_FS_DP
PA5.Mode=RX_Only_Simplex_Unidirect_Master
PA5.Signal=SPI1_SCK
PA6.Mode=RX_Only_Simplex_Unidirect_Master
PA6.Signal=SPI1_MISO
PA8.Locked=true
PA8.Signal=USB_OTG_FS_SOF
PA9.Locked=true
PA9.Mode=Activate_VBUS
PA9.Signal=USB_OTG_FS_VBUS
PB0.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PB0.GPIO_Label=LD1 [Green Led]
PB0.Locked=true
PB0.Signal=GPIO_Output
PB14.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PB14.GPIO_Label=LD3 [Red Led]
PB14.Locked=true
PB14.Signal=GPIO_Output
PC0.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PC0.GPIO_Label=I0
PC0.Locked=true
PC0.Signal=GPIO_Input
PC13.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PC13.GPIO_Label=B1 [Blue PushButton]
PC13.Locked=true
PC13.Signal=GPIO_Input
PC14-OSC32_IN\ (OSC32_IN).Locked=true
PC14-OSC32_IN\ (OSC32_IN).Signal=RCC_OSC32_IN
PC15-OSC32_OUT\ (OSC32_OUT).Locked=true
PC15-OSC32_OUT\ (OSC32_OUT).Signal=RCC_OSC32_OUT
PC3_C.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PC3_C.GPIO_Label=I1
PC3_C.Locked=true
PC3_C.Signal=GPIO_Input
PD10.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PD10.GPIO_Label=USB_OTG_FS_PWR_EN
PD10.Locked=true
PD10.Signal=GPIO_Output
PD7.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Speed,GPIO_Label
PD7.GPIO_Label=OUT
PD7.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH
PD7.Locked=true
PD7.Signal=GPIO_Output
PD8.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PD8.GPIO_Label=STLINK_RX
PD8.Locked=true
PD8.Mode=Asynchronous
PD8.Signal=USART3_TX
PD9.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PD9.GPIO_Label=STLINK_TX
PD9.Locked=true
PD9.Mode=Asynchronous
PD9.Signal=USART3_RX
PE1.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PE1.GPIO_Label=LD2 [Yellow Led]
PE1.Locked=true
PE1.Signal=GPIO_Output
PG7.GPIOParameters=GPIO_Label
PG7.GPIO_Label=USB_OTG_FS_OVCR
PG7.Locked=true
PG7.Signal=GPXTI7
PH0-OSC_IN\ (PH0).Locked=true
PH0-OSC_IN\ (PH0).Mode=HSE-External-Oscillator
PH0-OSC_IN\ (PH0).Signal=RCC_OSC_IN
PH1-OSC_OUT\ (PH1).Locked=true
PH1-OSC_OUT\ (PH1).Mode=HSE-External-Oscillator
PH1-OSC_OUT\ (PH1).Signal=RCC_OSC_OUT
PinOutPanel.RotationAngle=0
ProjectManager.AskForMigrate=true
ProjectManager.BackupPrevious=false
ProjectManager.CompilerOptimize=6
ProjectManager.ComputerToolchain=false
ProjectManager.CoupleFile=false
ProjectManager.CustomerFirmwarePackage=
ProjectManager.DefaultFWLocation=true
ProjectManager.DeletePrevious=true
ProjectManager.DeviceId=STM32H743ZITx
ProjectManager.FirmwarePackage=STM32Cube FW_H7 V1.10.0
ProjectManager.FreePins=false
ProjectManager.HalAssertFull=false
ProjectManager.HeapSize=0x200
ProjectManager.KeepUserCode=true
ProjectManager.LastFirmware=true
ProjectManager.LibraryCopy=1
ProjectManager.MainLocation=Core/Src
ProjectManager.NoMain=false
ProjectManager.PreviousToolchain=
ProjectManager.ProjectBuild=false
ProjectManager.ProjectFileName=MAX2771_Rec.ioc
ProjectManager.ProjectName=MAX2771_Rec
ProjectManager.RegisterCallBack=
ProjectManager.StackSize=0x400
ProjectManager.TargetToolchain=STM32CubeIDE
ProjectManager.ToolChainLocation=
ProjectManager.UnderRoot=true
ProjectManager.functionlistsort=1-SystemClock_Config-RCC-false-HAL-false,2-MX_GPIO_Init-GPIO-false-HAL-true,3-MX_USART3_UART_Init-USART3-false-HAL-true,4-MX_DMA_Init-DMA-false-HAL-true,5-MX_SPI1_Init-SPI1-false-HAL-true,6-MX_USB_DEVICE_Init-USB_DEVICE-false-HAL-false,0-MX_CORTEX_M7_Init-CORTEX_M7-false-HAL-true
RCC.ADCFreq_Value=16125000
RCC.AHB12Freq_Value=240000000
RCC.AHB4Freq_Value=240000000
RCC.APB1Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.APB2Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.APB3Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.APB4Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.AXIClockFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.CECFreq_Value=32000
RCC.CKPERFreq_Value=32000000
RCC.CortexFreq_Value=480000000
RCC.CpuClockFreq_Value=480000000
RCC.D1CPREFreq_Value=480000000
RCC.D1PPRE=RCC_APB3_DIV2
RCC.D2PPRE1=RCC_APB1_DIV2
RCC.D2PPRE2=RCC_APB2_DIV2
RCC.D3PPRE=RCC_APB4_DIV2
RCC.DFSDMACLkFreq_Value=64000000
RCC.DFSDMFreq_Value=120000000
RCC.DIVM1=1
RCC.DIVN1=120
RCC.DIVP1Freq_Value=480000000
RCC.DIVP2Freq_Value=16125000
RCC.DIVP3Freq_Value=16125000
RCC.DIVQ1=15
RCC.DIVQ1Freq_Value=64000000
RCC.DIVQ2Freq_Value=16125000
RCC.DIVQ3Freq_Value=16125000
RCC.DIVR1Freq_Value=480000000
RCC.DIVR2Freq_Value=16125000
RCC.DIVR3Freq_Value=16125000
RCC.FDCANFreq_Value=64000000
RCC.FMCFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.FamilyName=M
RCC.HCLK3ClockFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.HCLKFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.HPRE=RCC_HCLK_DIV2
RCC.HRTIMFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.HSE_VALUE=8000000
RCC.HSIDiv=RCC_PLLSAIDIVR_2
RCC.I2C123Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.I2C4Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.IPParameters=ADCFreq_Value,AHB12Freq_Value,AHB4Freq_Value,APB1Freq_Value,APB2Freq_Value,APB3Freq_Value,APB4Freq_Value,AXIClockFreq_Value,CECFreq_Value,CKPERFreq_Value,CortexFreq_Value,CpuClockFreq_Value,D1CPREFreq_Value,D1PPRE,D2PPRE1,D2PPRE2,D3PPRE,DFSDMACLkFreq_Value,DFSDMFreq_Value,DIVM1,DIVN1,DIVP1Freq_Value,DIVP2Freq_Value,DIVP3Freq_Value,DIVQ1,DIVQ1Freq_Value,DIVQ2Freq_Value,DIVQ3Freq_Value,DIVR1Freq_Value,DIVR2Freq_Value,DIVR3Freq_Value,FDCANFreq_Value,FMCFreq_Value,FamilyName,HCLK3ClockFreq_Value,HCLKFreq_Value,HPRE,HRTIMFreq_Value,HSE_VALUE,HSIDiv,I2C123Freq_Value,I2C4Freq_Value,LPTIM1Freq_Value,LPTIM2Freq_Value,LPTIM345Freq_Value,LPUART1Freq_Value,LTDCFreq_Value,MCO1PinFreq_Value,MCO2PinFreq_Value,PLL1_VCO_SEL,PLL2FRACN,PLL3FRACN,PLL3_VCO_SEL-AdvancedSettings,PLLFRACN,PLLSourceVirtual,PWR_Regulator_Voltage_Scale,QSPIFreq_Value,RNGFreq_Value,RTCFreq_Value,SAI1Freq_Value,SAI23Freq_Value,SAI4AFreq_Value,SAI4BFreq_Value,SDMMCFreq_Value,SPDIFRXFreq_Value,SPI123Freq_Value,SPI45Freq_Value,SPI6Freq_Value,SWPMI1Freq_Value,SYSCLKFreq_VALUE,SYSCLKSource,Tim1OutputFreq_Value,Tim2OutputFreq_Value,TraceFreq_Value,USART16Freq_Value,USART234578Freq_Value,USBFreq_Value,VCO1OutputFreq_Value,VCO2OutputFreq_Value,VCO3OutputFreq_Value,VCOInput1Freq_Value,VCOInput2Freq_Value,VCOInput3Freq_Value
RCC.LPTIM1Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.LPTIM2Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.LPTIM345Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.LPUART1Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.LTDCFreq_Value=16125000
RCC.MCO1PinFreq_Value=32000000
RCC.MCO2PinFreq_Value=480000000
RCC.PLL1_VCO_SEL=RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE
RCC.PLL2FRACN=0
RCC.PLL3FRACN=0
RCC.PLL3_VCO_SEL-AdvancedSettings=RCC_PLL3VCOMEDIUM
RCC.PLLFRACN=0
RCC.PLLSourceVirtual=RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE
RCC.PWR_Regulator_Voltage_Scale=PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE0
RCC.QSPIFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.RNGFreq_Value=48000000
RCC.RTCFreq_Value=32000
RCC.SAI1Freq_Value=64000000
RCC.SAI23Freq_Value=64000000
RCC.SAI4AFreq_Value=64000000
RCC.SAI4BFreq_Value=64000000
RCC.SDMMCFreq_Value=64000000
RCC.SPDIFRXFreq_Value=64000000
RCC.SPI123Freq_Value=64000000
RCC.SPI45Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.SPI6Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.SWPMI1Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.SYSCLKFreq_VALUE=480000000
RCC.SYSCLKSource=RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK
RCC.Tim1OutputFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.Tim2OutputFreq_Value=240000000
RCC.TraceFreq_Value=32000000
RCC.USART16Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.USART234578Freq_Value=120000000
RCC.USBFreq_Value=64000000
RCC.VCO1OutputFreq_Value=960000000
RCC.VCO2OutputFreq_Value=32250000
RCC.VCO3OutputFreq_Value=32250000
RCC.VCOInput1Freq_Value=8000000
RCC.VCOInput2Freq_Value=250000
RCC.VCOInput3Freq_Value=250000
SH.GPXTI0.0=GPIO_EXTI0
SH.GPXTI0.ConfNb=1
SH.GPXTI7.0=GPIO_EXTI7
SH.GPXTI7.ConfNb=1
SPI1.CLKPhase=SPI_PHASE_2EDGE
SPI1.CalculateBaudRate=32.0 MBits/s
SPI1.DataSize=SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT
SPI1.Direction=SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_RXONLY
SPI1.FirstBit=SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB
SPI1.IPParameters=VirtualType,Mode,Direction,DataSize,FirstBit,CLKPhase,CalculateBaudRate
SPI1.Mode=SPI_MODE_MASTER
SPI1.VirtualType=VM_MASTER
USART3.IPParameters=VirtualMode-Asynchronous,Mode
USART3.Mode=MODE_TX_RX
USART3.VirtualMode-Asynchronous=VM_ASYNC
USB_DEVICE.CLASS_NAME_FS=CDC
USB_DEVICE.IPParameters=VirtualMode-CDC_FS,VirtualModeFS,CLASS_NAME_FS,PRODUCT_STRING_CDC_FS
USB_DEVICE.PRODUCT_STRING_CDC_FS=STM32 Virtual Port
USB_DEVICE.VirtualMode-CDC_FS=Cdc
USB_DEVICE.VirtualModeFS=Cdc_FS
USB_OTG_FS.IPParameters=VirtualMode
USB_OTG_FS.VirtualMode=Device_Only
VP_SYS_VS_Systick.Mode=SysTick
VP_SYS_VS_Systick.Signal=SYS_VS_Systick
VP_USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS.Mode=CDC_FS
VP_USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS.Signal=USB_DEVICE_VS_USB_DEVICE_CDC_FS
board=NUCLEO-H743ZI2
boardIOC=true
isbadioc=false
```

Comment: You should at least specify which ADC. Typically you'll need to configure it, so transmit is necessary; also, post your .ioc file which contains the hardware setup in "readable" form. Show a schematic with your connections and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: the ADC is a part of GNSS front-end (https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2771.pdf) the ADC (page 20) output is mainly  parallel, but I can set it to serial transmission using DSP interface(in page 22).

Comment: I edited the file.